# Why do I get this Cloud Firestore Function error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I get this error in the [Cloud Firestore Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) log view.
I'm new to JavaScript and Firestore and could use some advice on this

> TypeError: event.data.previous.data is not a function at
>   exports.onVisitorPres...

```
exports.onVisitorPresenceWrite = functions.database
    .ref("/VISITORS_PRESENCE/{uid1}/{uid2}").onWrite((event) => {
        // Get the data written or deleted on the Realtime Database
        var eventStatus = event.data.val();
        const previousData = event.data.previous.data();
        // If the onWrite event is a delete event then use previousData
        if(eventStatus == null){
            eventStatus = previousData;
        }
    });
```

What I want to do is using the `.onWrite((event)` on a Firebase Realtime databas key and Firestore Function trigger when the key items get deleted and when new items are added.
I thought I could check the `eventStatus == null` and that is when data is deleted I simply use the previousData (before it got delete??)

Comment: I think you're confusing/mixing [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) & [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) triggers here - your code example is for the Realtime Database, but the question also mentions (and is tagged for) Firestore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `event` variable is an instance of [`Event`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Event) and therefore calling `event.data` will return a [`DeltaDocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.firestore.DeltaDocumentSnapshot) for Firestore and a [`DeltaSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot) for the Realtime Database.

With a these delta snapshots, you can obtain the previous value with [`previous`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.firestore.DeltaDocumentSnapshot#previous) which will return another `DeltaDocumentSnapshot` or `DeltaSnapshot` containing the previous state from before the write event was triggered.

In your example, you're using a Firebase Realtime Database trigger, which means `event.data.previous` will return a `DeltaSnapshot`, which does not support `data()`, but instead supports `val()`.

In this case, as you've done with `var eventStatus = event.data.val();`, you need to call `val()` on `previous`:

```
const previousData = event.data.previous.val();
```

If instead you are trying to use a Firestore trigger, you need to change this:

```
functions.database.ref("[...]")
```

To this:

```
functions.firestore.document("[...]")
```

And then you can use `event.data.previous.data()`.

Comment: Strange the word "val()" is not mention on this page [functions firestore-events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events)

Comment: Actually I see what's happened, your example is for [Firebase Realtime Database onWrite trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events), see my edited answer.

Comment: Thansk Grimthorr yes you right ok just started learning this :)